# Clang's 'scan-build' utilite does not work with 'make'

Tags: gcc, cmake, clang, scan-build

I'm trying to statically analyze my code via Clang's static code analyzer tool `scan-build` and when I run the code with `scan-build g++` command, it provides me a bug report, but when I'm trying to do same thing with CMake and the `scan-build make` command, it tells me that no bugs were found.

I've already tried to substitute `CC` and `CXX` variables by bash export command, used `--use_cc` and `--use_c++` flags and built separate targets using `scan-build make TARGET`. All of this did not lead me to the correct solution and I'm afraid that `scan-build` could not work with CMake/make.

- Clang version 8.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_800/final)
- Gcc version 7.4.0 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04)

Here is a simple example.

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER    "usr/bin/clang")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER  "usr/bin/clang++")
set(CMAKE_AR            "usr/bin/llvm-ar")
set(CMAKE_LINKER        "usr/bin/llvm-ld")
set(CMAKE_NM            "usr/bin/llvm-nm")
set(CMAKE_OBJDUMP       "usr/bin/llvm-objdump")
set(CMAKE_RANLIB        "usr/bin/llvm-ranlib")

project(scan-build-test)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int *a;
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}
```

#### Current behavior g++:

```
scan-build g++ main.cpp -o main
scan-build: Using 'usr/bin/clang-8' for static analysis main.cpp:6:2: warning: 1st function call argument is an uninitialized value
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
scan-build: 1 bug found.
scan-build: Run 'scan-view /tmp/scan-build-2019-05-30-134021-30676-1' to examine bug reports.`
```

#### Current behavior CMake & make:

```
cmake .
scan-build make
scan-build: Using 'usr/bin/clang-8' for static analysis
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/scan-build-test.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable scan-build-test
[100%] Built target scan-build-test
scan-build: Removing directory '/tmp/scan-build-2019-05-30-134302-30720-1' because it contains no reports.
scan-build: No bugs found.
```

Comment: `scan-build cmake .` try this

Comment: Nope, still same `No bugs found.` message both for `scan-build cmake .` and for `scan-build make`

Comment: Could you please show your logs? Here is mine https://gist.github.com/snikulov/b2d6c6e0571defdd2e4dd7d529df6283

Comment: And one note - I've removed all set's from CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Well, thank you very much, your last note helped me to raise up `scan-build`. I don't understand one thing - why doesn't it work with clang compiler? And why does it work with gcc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All static analysis (and other source code related) instruments for C/C++ need to replicate the compilation process for each source file in your project. In order to get everything right, they need to have all the compilation options (like macro definitions and include directories) that were used during the real compilation.

There are a few ways to do it. Without getting into much details about other approaches, here's how `scan-build` does it. 
It substitutes the real compiler with its wrapper executable, receives all the compiler commands from the build system, does its job and forwards all the same options to the real compiler.

That's why direct SET commands for compiler in your `CMakeLists.txt` file prevented `scan-build` from doing its trick. It will work with both *gcc* and *clang*, but you should not hardcode them and use `CC` and `CXX` environment variables instead.